# Windows RAMDisk Storage Driver Sample. Drive with the name 'R' does not exist

Tags: driver, storage, windows-10, wdk, ramdisk

**Context**: Playing with Microsoft [RAMDisk Storage Driver Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/storage/ramdisk). Build and installation of the driver went smoothly. Verified that the Ramdisk service exist in the registry, and could see the Ramdisk device in Device Manager.

**Issue**: When trying to access the Ramdisk device (Drive R:) via *Windows PowerShell* to perform IO I get the following error message:

```
Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'R' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1

Set-Location R:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (R:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Attempted to access the Ramdisk via *Command Prompt* and *File Explorer* without success.

**Question**: What am I doing wrong?

**Development Environment**:

- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- Visual Studio 2015
- WDK 10

**Target Environment**:

- Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation 64-bit (Build 10586)
- Debug and Test mode enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root Cause**: The Ramdisk sample driver is not properly handling disk device requests for Windows 10.

**Solution**: Updated the Ramdisk sample driver to properly handle disk device request. See [Windows driver sample pull request #53](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/pull/53) for details.

**Note**: This code has only been tested on Windows 10, and will only allow you to access the Ramdisk via *Windows PowerShell*, or *Command Prompt*. *File Explorer* still doesn't work; please let me know, if anyone was able to get *File Explorer* working.